# Matplotlib package is installed, and the code is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code is not working, but in the site "repl.it" it´s working!,
nothing happens, the fig.show() should print a graphic chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seq_human = {'AA': 116, 'AT': 95, 'AC': 97, 'AG': 113, 'TA': 85, 'TT': 113, 'TC': 109, 'TG': 111, 'CA': 87, 'CT': 105, 'CC': 184, 'CG': 170, 'GA': 134, 'GT': 105, 'GC': 155, 'GG': 184}
seq_bacteria = {'AA': 105, 'AT': 64, 'AC': 86, 'AG': 111, 'TA': 64, 'TT': 57, 'TC': 60, 'TG': 108, 'CA': 83, 'CT': 75, 'CC': 74, 'CG': 97, 'GA': 113, 'GT': 93, 'GC': 109, 'GG': 147}


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 5))

ax1.bar(seq_human.keys(), seq_human.values(), width=0.4, align='edge', label='Human: 18S rRNA gene')
ax1.bar(seq_bacteria.keys(), seq_bacteria.values(), width=-0.4, align='edge', label='Bacteria: Escherichia coli 16S ribosomal')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax1.set_xlabel('Nitrogenous Bases')
ax1.legend()
fig.show()
```

Comment: Give us error message etc. Plus make your code reproducible.

Comment: now u can reproducible the code, there is no error message.

Comment: Then what does "is not working" mean?

Comment: nothing happens, the fig.show() should print a graphic chart.

Comment: `plt.show()`... though your second subplot will be empty as you only plotted data in `ax1`.

Comment: thanks man, thanks a lot..., it was lack of attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc string of `fig.show`

> Warning:
>
> This does not manage an GUI event loop. Consequently, the figure
>      may only be shown briefly or not shown at all if you or your
>      environment are not managing an event loop.
>
> Proper use cases for `.Figure.show` include running this from a
>      GUI application or an IPython shell.
>
> **If you're** running a pure python shell or **executing a non-GUI
>      python script, you should use `matplotlib.pyplot.show` instead**,
>      which takes care of managing the event loop for you.

emphasis is mine…